# understanding sub function in R

Tags: r, pattern-matching

I have a string like this `"HsdkjnsjHlksmH"`. In the string, I want to replace only the second by a 'Q'.

I know this code `sub("H*.H", "Q", s)` can do it. But, I can't understand what the `H*.H` mean here.

Could someone explain please. I'm very new to R.

Comment: I think that you actually need `"H.*?H"`

Comment: See your pattern explanation [here](https://regex101.com/r/NVeLs8/1).

Comment: It says the * after H should match the character 'H' between 0 and unlimited times in the string. That means it should also match thr first occurrence of 'H'. Why doesn't that happen?